# value in cookie is not refreshed after click again on an anchor tag

Tags: jquery, cookies, anchor

I have a multi-language login site and I want to store the login information (user & language) in cookie using jQuery. The form has 2 anchor tags and some labels which changes dynamically based on the chosen language.

```
<form id="frm0" method="post" action="">
  <fieldset>
    <div id="lng" style="text-align: right">
      <a href="index.php?lang=en" id="en" title="English"><img src="pics/files/en.png" alt="English" /></a>&nbsp;
      <a href="index.php?lang=de" id="de" title="Deutsch"><img src="pics/files/de.png" alt="Deutsch" /></a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="usr" style="font-weight: bold">User for en/Benutzer for de: </label>
      <input name="usr" type="text" id="usr">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="passw" style="font-weight: bold">Password for en/Kennwort for de: </label>
      <input name="passw" type="password" id="passw">
    </div>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" name="sbmt" id="sbmt" value="Login">
</form>
```

The following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a').click(function(){
      var language = $(this).attr("id");
      $.cookie('lang', language, { path: '/', expires: 14 });
  });
});
```

sets the cookie correctly, but only after one click on an anchor tag. If I change the language again, the value of the cookie is not refreshed. However, if I add "return false":

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a').click(function(){
      var language = $(this).attr("id");
      $.cookie('lang', language, { path: '/', expires: 14 });
      return false;
  });
});
```

the value of the cookie is set correctly after every click on the anchor tag, but the labels on the page does not change based on the selected language (its like the page is not refreshed).

I've also tried with:

```
  $('#lng a').click(function() {
    $.cookie('lang', this.id, { path: '/', expires: 14 });
    return false;
  });
```

but the same bahaviour.
Any help please? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `return false` is preventing your anchor from clicking, hence the cookie being set but the page **not** refreshing, and therefore your language not changing.

You could try something like below:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $('a').click(function(event)
   {
        var language = $(this).attr("id");
        alert(language);
        $.cookie('lang', language, { path: '/', expires: 14 });
        e.preventDefault(event);
        alert($.cookie('lang'));
        window.location($(this).attr("href"));
   });
 });
```

However, I'd assume it's the same as `return false` and you'll have the same result. I'd be checking that the cookie is changing, and that it's not more around the page refresh and link destination.

Can you let us know what both the alerts are returning please? I have a feeling it's to do with the load process.

As the Url has the language in it, is it worth checking on the page load?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var language = $.cookie("lang");
     if(language.length > 0)
     { // Do things for the set language }
     else
     {
       language = $.QueryString["lang"];
       $.cookie("lang", language);
       // Do things for QueryString language
     }
   alert(language); // If you want to check the language set?
```

});

And you can get the QueryString values from this SO question: [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values)

Lots of options for getting the QueryString value, but my personal preference is for BrunoLM's answer.

Comment: Same thing. The cookie is set ONLY after the first click! And the alerts are issued ONLY after the 1st click too. Both the alerts are returning the correct language (i.e. de for Deutsch, en for English), but like I said only once. If I click again on another language -> no alerts & no set of the cookie. Instead, if I add "return false", the alerts & the cookie are set every time correctly, but no refresh of the labels. I will keep trying, but for the moment I'm stuck. Basically, all I need is an equivalent to "return false" which also allows the labels to be refreshed.

Comment: On the 1st page load, the URL has no string at all (for instance example.com), after the first click on an anchor tag it changes to example.com/index.php?lang=en/de. If I load the page with index.php?lang=en (or de), the cookie is set correctly thru QueryString. 

`if($.cookie('lang') == null) $.cookie("lang", ""); 
var language = $.cookie("lang"); 
if (language.length > 0) 
{ alert('cookie already set'); } 
else { 
language = $.QueryString["lang"]; 
$.cookie("lang", language); } 
alert(language);`

Comment: The fact the return false / preventDefault allows the cookie to be set implies some kind of timing issue - I take if you do want the page redirected on the language button click? And the cookie set at the same time? If so, I'd look to default the cookie on load, and set it with the new query string as and when required. Let me know, and I can knock up some more code to explain what I'm thinking

Comment: I've changed to `window.location.href = $(this).attr("href");` and everything is working fine. Thank you for your support.